# substr() expects parameter 1 to be string (SQL SERVER PHP 5 to PHP 7)

Tags: php, sql-server, php-7

i'm trying to change php 5 to php 7, but i got error, the code i already try like this

```
for($a=0;$a<sqlsrv_num_rows($db);$a++){
$db1=sqlsrv_fetch_array($db, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

$tes=$a+1;
$tanggal=substr($db1["pdate"],0,11);

?>
<tr>
<td align=center>
<font size=2><?php echo $tes++;?></font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<font size=2><?php echo $tanggal;?></font>
</td>

<td align=center>
<font size=2><?php echo $db1["gametype"];?></font>
</td>
<td align=center>
<?php
if($db1["gametype"]=="TXH"){
?>
        <font size=2?><?php echo "".curr($db1["txhresult"])."";?></font>
        <?php
    $duit+=$db1["txhresult"];
}
?>
}
```

result from `var_dump ($db1["pdate"])`

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-09-16 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Asia/Jakarta" }
```

it tell `substr() expects parameter 1 to be string`i how to fix this? appreciate any help thanks

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($db1["pdate"], $dpo["date2"])` to see what type the variables are? Clearly they weren't strings, but this requires some debugging on your part to figure out why they weren't what you expected them to be. Also, I notice you use `$dpo["date2"]`, but you never initialized a variable named `$dpo` anywhere in this code. Perhaps a typo?

Comment: yes i'm already try to `var_dump($db1["pdate"])` and ignore the `$dpo["date2"]` i'm forgot to put into comment, i will update result from var_dump

Comment: OK, well **clearly** a `DateTime` object isn't a string.

Comment: i think i should take a rest for bit, lol, thanks btw